# Why do the values change when I run this basic C program?

Tags: c

I've started learning C, and am referencing a book and the freeCodeCamp YouTube channel. I typed out a basic C program to calculate gross salary. Usually, the program runs without a problem, but sometimes the one value I have to enter is altered in the command prompt. The code and an example of the issue are given below.

```
//calculate gross salary of a nondescript guy who is totally not Clark Kent
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float bs, da, hra, gs;
    printf("\nEnter basic salary of guy: ");
    scanf("%f", &bs);
    da = 0.4 * bs;
    hra = 0.2 * bs;
    gs = da + hra + bs;
    printf("Basic salary of Guy = %f\n", bs);
    printf("Dearness allowance = %f\n", da);
    printf("House Rent Allowance = %f\n", hra);
    printf("Gross Salary = %f\n", gs);
    return 0;
}
```

[Command Prompt output screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEcsM.png)

I have no idea why it happens. I've tried other values, and like I said the programs runs totally fine then.
I'm new, so it might be some sort of theoretical limitation of values I'm yet to learn, but any help would be appreciated.
P.S. I'm using Code::Blocks as my IDE if it matters.

Comment: what about when you change `float` to `double`? If it works, you should focus on the underneath diff btw the two types.

Comment: @snr i tried what you said and it worked fabulously, thank you, but what could be the reason for it messing up with the float keyword? Also, what did you say i should focus on again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using the datatype called `double` instead of `float` as it has higher accuracy (double the precision of that of the `float` to be more specific).

you have to know how is `float` or `double` is represented, as the value **0.59392** is actually stored in the memory as value **0.593900024890899658203125** when using float according to IEEE 754 standard and the number **123456789** is stored as **123456792**, so there are other types of decimals to solve this problem where the difference between them is as follow

- Decimal representation gives lower accuracy but a higher range with big
  numbers and high accuracy when talking about small numbers, most 2
  used standards are binary integer decimal (BID) and densely packed decimal (DPD)
- float and doubles gives higher accuracy than Decimal when talking
  about big numbers but lower range ,they follow IEEE 754 standard
- Fixed-Point types have the lowest range but they are the most accurate one and they are the fastest ones

but remember that only `double` and `float` are C standards while `_Decimal64` or `_Fract` or any other datatype are compiler specific.

you can refer to any online tutorial to learn how is `float` and `decimal` represented in the memory like [this small tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ieee-standard-754-floating-point-numbers/)

Comment: 123456789 is not “stored as“ 123456792. When a numeral is parsed, it is converted to a numeric format. When the value of the numeral is not representable in the format, so other value must be produced. This is not a representation of the original value; it is a different value. This is important for the model of floating-point computing, so that students do not think floating-point numbers represent approximations, intervals, or nearby numbers…

Comment: … As IEEE 754 specifies floating-point arithmetic, each floating-point value that is not an infinity or a NaN represents one specific number **exactly**. In floating-point, the numbers are exact, and it is the operations that approximate real-number arithmetic. Each operation produces a result equivalent to performing the real-number-arithmetic operation and then rounding it to a result representable in the floating-point format. Converting a decimal numeral in input text to a floating-point value is one such operation. That operation rounds the number before it is ever stored.